# NetBeans - Display .gitignore Files in Projects/Files

Tags: netbeans, gitignore

By default, NetBeans does not show .gitignore files inside it's Projects/Files lists.

How do I get them to show up?

I'd like to see them, since NetBeans has no issue actually editing these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the NetBeans Options
- Click on the 'Files' tab
- Under 'Ignored Files Pattern', the default is:

  `^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!htaccess$).*$`
- This means that, by default, NetBeans ignores all files beginning with '.' except for .htaccess
- You can update this regex to the following to also exclude .gitignore:

  `^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|gitignore)$).*$`
- Click OK, and NetBeans will immediately begin displaying your .gitignore files.

Comment: On NetBeans 8.2 the **Ignored Files Pattern** is located at Tools (Menu) > Options (menu entry) > Miscellaneous (main tab) > Files (section tab). The default regex is `^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(git|hg|svn|cache|DS_Store)$|^Thumbs.db$` which doesn't match the `.gitignore` file, but there's a option bellow to **Ignore all .doted files in home folder** that should be disabled to make the file show in the project tree. In my case it didn't work, any idea how to solve it?